# Поиск ключа в многомерном массиве, проверка существует или нет

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

Ребята, только учусь. 
Есть массив

```
{
        "id": 2,
        "firstName": "Тест",
        "lastName": "Тест",
        "patronymic": "Тест",
        "sexId": 101252,
        "mobilePhone": "71111111111",
        "registrationNumber": {
            "id": 6,
            "seria": "",
            "no": "",
            "extraNumber": "",
            "issueDate": null,
            "closeDate": null,
            "manager": "",
            "subdivisionCode": "",
            "complementaryDocTypeId": null
        },
        "personRelatives": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "lastName": "dsv",
                "firstName": "sd",
                "patronymic": "",
                "resident": false,
                "passport": {
                    "id": 43,
                    "seria": "",
                    "no": "",
                    "extraNumber": null,
                    "issueDate": null,
                    "closeDate": null,
                    "manager": "",
                    "subdivisionCode": "",
                    "complementaryDocTypeId": null
                },
                "rnn": "",
                "telephone": "",
                "email": "",
                "workPlace": "",
                "address": "",
                "birthDate": null,
                "collateralRelId": 102147,
                "verified": null,
                "comments": ""
            }
        ],
        "clientRiskStatus": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "insertDate": 1539244552517,
                "userId": 1027,
                "comments": "3211",
                "valueId": 102184
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "insertDate": 1540396776913,
                "userId": 1027,
                "comments": "321",
                "valueId": 102184
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "insertDate": 1540397890848,
                "userId": 1027,
                "comments": "123",
                "valueId": 102184
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "insertDate": 1540398590878,
                "userId": 1027,
                "comments": "авлоавыолз",
                "valueId": 102184
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "insertDate": 1539067291379,
                "userId": 1027,
                "comments": "Новый клиент",
                "valueId": 102185
            }
        ],
        "extraFields": [
            {
                "id": 178,
                "key": "placeOfEducation",
                "value": "kzt1"
            },
            {
                "id": 179,
                "key": "work1",
                "value": "workk1"
            },
            {
                "id": 180,
                "key": "work2",
                "value": null
            },
            {
                "id": 181,
                "key": "work3",
                "value": null
            },
            {
                "id": 183,
                "key": "work6",
                "value": ""
            }]}
```

Задача - проверить существует ли ключ, если да, то изменить значение, если нет, то создать новый.
Ребята подсказали как менять значение

```
$needle1 = "work3";
foreach($response1['data']['extraFields'] as $key => $val){
    if($val['key'] == "work3"){ // находим нужный ключ
        $response1['data']['extraFields'][$key]['value'] = 'new value'; 
    }
}
```

так же есть понимание как создать новый.

```
$DDD = array("id" => "1001", "key" => "NEW" , "value" => $Comm1);
array_push($response1['data']['extraFields'], $DDD);
```

А вот как объединить их никак не могу понять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$json = '{
        "id": 2,
        "firstName": "Тест",
        "lastName": "Тест",
        "patronymic": "Тест",
        "sexId": 101252,
        "mobilePhone": "71111111111",
        "registrationNumber": {
            "id": 6,
            "seria": "",
            "no": "",
            "extraNumber": "",
            "issueDate": null,
            "closeDate": null,
            "manager": "",
            "subdivisionCode": "",
            "complementaryDocTypeId": null
        },
        "personRelatives": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "lastName": "dsv",
                "firstName": "sd",
                "patronymic": "",
                "resident": false,
                "passport": {
                    "id": 43,
                    "seria": "",
                    "no": "",
                    "extraNumber": null,
                    "issueDate": null,
                    "closeDate": null,
                    "manager": "",
                    "subdivisionCode": "",
                    "complementaryDocTypeId": null
                },
                "rnn": "",
                "telephone": "",
                "email": "",
                "workPlace": "",
                "address": "",
                "birthDate": null,
                "collateralRelId": 102147,
                "verified": null,
                "comments": ""
            }
        ],
        "clientRiskStatus": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "insertDate": 1539244552517,
                "userId": 1027,
                "comments": "3211",
                "valueId": 102184
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "insertDate": 1540396776913,
                "userId": 1027,
                "comments": "321",
                "valueId": 102184
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "insertDate": 1540397890848,
                "userId": 1027,
                "comments": "123",
                "valueId": 102184
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "insertDate": 1540398177463,
                "userId": 1027,
                "comments": "вшозавц",
                "valueId": 102184
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "insertDate": 1540398590878,
                "userId": 1027,
                "comments": "авлоавыолз",
                "valueId": 102184
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "insertDate": 1539067291379,
                "userId": 1027,
                "comments": "Новый клиент",
                "valueId": 102185
            }
        ],
        "extraFields": [
            {
                "id": 178,
                "key": "placeOfEducation",
                "value": "kzt1"
            },
            {
                "id": 179,
                "key": "work1",
                "value": "workk1"
            },
            {
                "id": 180,
                "key": "work2",
                "value": null
            },
            {
                "id": 181,
                "key": "work3",
                "value": null
            },
            {
                "id": 182,
                "key": "placeOfEducation1",
                "value": "kzt1"
            },
            {
                "id": 183,
                "key": "work6",
                "value": ""
            }]}';

$json = json_decode($json, true);
```

---

```
$key = array_search("work6888", array_column($json['extraFields'], 'key'));

if($key){
    $json['extraFields'][$key]['value'] = "new value";
} else {
    $json['extraFields'][] = array(
        'id' => 'new id',
        'key' => 'new key',
        'value' => 'new value'
    );
}
```

Результат

```
[6]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(6) "new id"
    ["key"]=>
    string(7) "new key"
    ["value"]=>
    string(9) "new value"
  }
```

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо!
Это правильный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Ну допустим так для наглядности (оптимальность слегка пропустим)

```
$needle1 = "work3";
foreach($response1['data']['extraFields'] as $key => $val){
    if(!$response1['data']['extraFields'][$key]['key']) $response1['data']['extraFields'][$key]['key']='new value';
    if($val['key'] == "work3"){ // находим нужный ключ
        $response1['data']['extraFields'][$key]['value'] = 'new value'; 
    }
}
```

Возможно не правильно понял и "ключ" не key, а value. Тогда так

```
if(!$response1['data']['extraFields'][$key]['value']) $response1['data']['extraFields'][$key]['value']='new value';
```

Comment: Эм. Ваше первое условие не сработает, т.к в каждом массиве `$response1['data']['extraFields'][$key]` есть ключ `key`.

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев, а второе?

Comment: @Nsk Наверно, не совсем корректно уточнил. Мне необходимо найти не значение 'new value', а ключ work3 например. Если этот ключ существует, тогда изменить, если нет, то поменять значение.<br/>  "key": "work3", work3 -ключ. "value": null а это его значение.